# Can't boot gentoo from usb

Tags: usb, gentoo

I'm trying to install gentoo from usb. I'm using windows7 I downloaded the amd64 in: iso ( install-cd on this page: https://www.gentoo.org/main/en/where.xml then used Unetbooting to burn it on my usb. For some reason in the choices of distributions gentoo does not appear so I don't select any distribution. It worked before but now when I select the default option after reboot it says the iso is corrupt. I tried on another usb  key, tried with lili usb creator, win32diskimage, universal-usb-installer, yumi, sardux64 and none of these work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try just copy byte-to-byte liveDVD iso to you flash drive. Use dd command for this (under Win you can find some analogs).
The good article about Gentoo on USB: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/LiveUSB/HOWTO

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I realized that the guide I was referring to assumed the user used uefi so at that point it was irrelevant. Strange thing is rufus burns the iso image better then unetbooting

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use UNetbootin.

First select the Diskimage radio button. Next push the three dots button to select the iso install-amd64-minimal-20140828.iso. Next select the usb drive and push the ok button.

Your machine should be using legacy bios to boot the usb. On my dell I push F12 on the bios screen for a boot menu and then select usb to start.

Once grub comes up select gentoo to use the usb drive.

The minimal install cd has worked great but any live disk can be used. The live disk is only used to connect to the internet, prepare the disks, copy the stage 3, and chroot into the disks. Most distributions have live disks that can do this.